# Using TPM AIK for decryption

Tags: tpm

I am working on a project using TPMs & am trying to figure out if the AIKs can be used to decrypt any blob of text?

I was able to get my head around AIK enrollment & am now trying to use it for identity. For that my plan is to send a blob of text encrypted with AIK public key & ask the platform to decrypt it for me.

I thought of an alternate approach to have the AIK sign a blob of text for me at first, but looks like AIKs can be used to sign only the PCRs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as a signing key the AIK is not meant to be used for decryption. You may be misunderstanding the purpose of the AIK. It is almost exclusively used for signing system quotes (obtained via TPM_Quote) which is then checked against the AIK certificate signed by a CA you trust. [Intro to TPM 1.2](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5204/fall10-kafura-BB/Papers/TPM/Intro-TPM.pdf) explains well how the EK and AIK play together.